# Finding in a set of struct in c++

Tags: c++, set

```
struct data
{
    int price;
    int qty;

    bool operator<(const data&rhs)const
    {
        return price<rhs.price;
    }
    bool operator==(const data&rhs)const
    {
        return price==rhs.price;
     }
};

set<data> bar;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    data info;
    set<data>::iterator iter;
    int a[10]={100,120,500,142,142,245,62,52,12,1};

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        info.price=a[i];
        info.qty=a[i];
        //some logic to find the price and if found then simply add the qty



        //********This part of the code doesnt work(NO ERROR)*********
              iter=bar.find(info);//Find before insert
              info.qty+=(*iter).qty;//then add
       //******************************************

        bar.insert(info);
        //code to print the set
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I want to find if the price is already present in the `set`, and if so I want to add the quantity.
e.g. Since 142 is added to the `set`, when it finds the next `142` in `a` it should add that to the existing entry.
I know how to do this with map but since it is a set of struct, i am not able to manipulate it

Final Desired Output:

> Price...Qty
>   1...........1
>   12.........12
>   52.........52
>   62.........62
>   100.......100
>   120.......120
>   142.......284 ///Here it finds and then adds the qty
>   245.......245
>   500.......500

Comment: I think you're simply looking for [`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find), or if you wish to find the price before inserting into the `set` (like your code comment indicates) you can use `std::find` (which you can also use for a `set`)

Comment: Elements of `std::set` are const. You cannot modify one, by adding `qty` or otherwise. The best you can do is remove the existing element and insert a modified element back.

Comment: Yes, it is not inserting the desired value. Thanks. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: FYI I have edited your question to hopefully clarify what you are asking; however, if I've done so incorrectly you are free to rollback my edit or [edit] it further to explain exactly what you want.

Comment: sounds like you want an `std::map<int, int>` that correlates a price to a quantity. then, you'd just need `bar[a[i]] += a[i]`

Comment: Please provide compilable code in your question (you're missing an `#include` and perhaps `using namespace std;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by others, access to items in a set is via a `const` reference so you cannot normally modify them. This problem is well suited to a map.

The reason why your code compiles is because one line is backwards:

```
          info.qty+=(*iter).qty;//then add
```

Should be:

```
          (*iter).qty+=info.qty;//then add
```

Just making this change will give a compilation error. If you must use a set, you can also mark the `qty` member mutable to avoid the error:

```
mutable int qty;
```

Using `mutable` for this would probably be considered bad practice by many, however. The issue is that *any* `const` reference to a `data` object now allows the `qty` member to be mutated.